# Linq-to-SQL date format: query does not work

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, datetimepicker

I have a stored procedure when I am executing this query in SQL Server

```
exec SelectOfficeNameGroup  '2011-10-05', '2011-11-09', ''
```

it returns 110 rows.

Now I have two datepicker on my c# 3.5 form and one button which executes the query like this:

```
var result = context.SelectOfficeNameGroup(dateTimePickerFrom.Value, dateTimePickerTo.Value, "");
```

but its only returns 2 rows.

My date picker's format is `MM/DD/YYYY`

This is my procedure

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SelectOfficeNameGroup]
  @From datetime,
  @To datetime,
  @OfficeName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT
      ID AS ProductID, OfficeName,  
      SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, 
      SUM(TotalPrice) AS TotalPrice, 
      Category
   FROM
      ProductLogWithCategory 
   WHERE 
      DateTime BETWEEN @From AND @To AND OfficeName = @OfficeName
   GROUP BY 
      OfficeName, ID, Category

  return
END
```

Any advice?

Comment: maybe you should convert your date to YYYY-MM-DD ?

Comment: Gaby aka G. Petrioli << i tried to make datepickers format custoom YYYY-MM-DD but returning value is MM/DD/YYYY. how i can convert?

Comment: @Acid, posted answer with the conversion..

Comment: Was any of the answers here helpful to you? I'm curious, because we use L2S with sprocs as well, so far without this kind of issues, so I wonder if we should be extra cautious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
var result = context.SelectOfficeNameGroup(dateTimePickerFrom.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), dateTimePickerTo.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "");
```

Have a look at the [DateTime.ToString <sup>documentation</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

---

**Update**

Just to be on the safe side try

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SelectOfficeNameGroup]
  @From varchar(8),
  @To varchar(8),
  @OfficeName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT
      ID AS ProductID, OfficeName,  
      SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, 
      SUM(TotalPrice) AS TotalPrice, 
      Category
   FROM
      ProductLogWithCategory 
   WHERE 
      DateTime BETWEEN @From AND @To AND OfficeName = @OfficeName
   GROUP BY 
      OfficeName, ID, Category

  return
END
```

and use it like this

***from sql***

```
exec SelectOfficeNameGroup  '20111005', '20111109', ''
```

***from linq***

```
var result = context.SelectOfficeNameGroup(dateTimePickerFrom.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), dateTimePickerTo.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), "");
```

Comment: its converto to string i need datetime. Error The best overloaded method match for 'Med.DataClasses1DataContext.SelectOfficeNameGroup(System.DateTime?, System.DateTime?, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Acid, does `exec SelectOfficeNameGroup  '2011-05-10', '2011-09-11', ''` return the same two as the linq version ? Maybe it is reading your text version as day-month instead of month-day

Comment: @Acid, I can only think that there is a wrong cast happening somewhere.. I would try changing the actual stored procedure to accept strings and pass it in the format `"yyyyMMdd"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Parse('your date in MM/DD/YYYY', new CultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: thanks but its says ErrorThe best overloaded method match for 'Med.DataClasses1DataContext.SelectOfficeNameGroup(System.DateTime?, System.DateTime?, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Acid, then remove the `.ToString`

Comment: sorry... but how ? just remove? DateTime.Parse(dateTimePickerFrom.Value.ToShortDateString(), new CultureInfo("en-US")); like this? but it still returning same